Subsite cannot be found using correct subsite ID, despite the fact that the subsite exists, using Microsoft Graph
I have an application that reads files from a subsite on Sharepoint. Application permissions are being used, and those permissions have been applied to the SiteId. Below is the relevant portion of the code:
DriveCollectionResponse docLibraries = await _graphHelper.GetBaseDocumentLibraryAsync(siteId, subSiteID);

string mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

string mimeTypeXlsm = "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12";

//Get the documents rood folder
Drive documentsFolder = docLibraries.Value.Where(x => x.DriveType == "documentLibrary" && x.Name == "Documents").FirstOrDefault();

List<DriveItem> documentsChildren = await _graphHelper.GetChildrenAsync(documentsFolder.Id);
DriveItem estimating03 = documentsChildren.Where(x => x.Name == "04 - Change Management").FirstOrDefault();

The first line is where it fails. If I remove the subsiteId, which is optional, it works, but the correct directory structure is not shown. If I run it as is, I get an error that reads "Requested site cannot be found". This code worked about 3 months ago, the last time it was used. So, I don't understand how this happened.
When you apply the permissions to the siteId, do you also need to apply them to the subsiteId?
I don't think it's a permissions issue, because I would think I would get an access denied error instead.
EDIT: Appologies, I created a utility class to route the methods I needed. In any event, I forgot to include the actual method being executed:
return await _graphServiceClient.Sites[subsiteId].Drives.GetAsync();


You are calling some helper method on the first line. Could you share the code of the helper method? Otherwise we can only guess what can be wrong.

Oops! Thanks for catching that! I updated the question with the MSGraph call.

Maybe try to check if the subsite exists. You should be able to list site's subsites => var subsites = await _graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId].Sites.GetAsync()
